# Lightbox not displaying images when using MySQL and PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, html, image, lightbox

I have encountered a small problem when trying to make my website more advanced. To put it simple:

when I wanted to display images in a table using Lightbox and PHP everyting worked well:

```
          <tr>
          <td class="w-25">
              <a href="telewizory/telewizor1.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-lightbox="telewizor1" class="col-sm-4" >
              <img src="telewizory/telewizor1.jpeg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Sheep">
          </td>
          <td>Philips 70PUS6704/12</td>
          <td>3999</td>
          </tr>
```

The first column presented the image, the second - name and the last one - price.
[how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBK6i.jpg)

However, when I wanted to add MySQL and created a database in PHPMyAdmin something went wrong. I can still read the name and the price well, but images don't show, I can only see the alternative text - Sheep in this example.

New code:

```
<?php
        $kat_id = isset($_GET['kat_id']) ? (int)$_GET['kat_id'] : 1;
        $sql = 'SELECT `img`, `nazwa` , `cena`
           FROM `produkty`
           WHERE `kategoria_id` = ' . $kat_id .
           ' ORDER BY `nazwa`';

        $wynik = mysqli_query($polaczenie, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($wynik) > 0) {
            while ($produkt = @mysqli_fetch_array($wynik)) {
            echo 
            '<tr>
                <td class="w-25">
                    <a href="telewizory/' . $produkt['img'] . ' data-toggle="lightbox" data-lightbox="' . substr($produkt['img'], 0, strpos($produkt['img'], ".")) . '" class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="telewizory/' . $produkt['img'] . ' class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Sheep">'
            . ' </td>
            <td>' . $produkt['nazwa'] . '</td>' 
            . '<td>' . $produkt['cena'] . '</td>
            </tr>' 
            . PHP_EOL;
        }

        } else {
        echo 'wyników 0';
        }
        mysqli_close($polaczenie);
        ?>
```

[how it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OJmv.jpg)

I have no idea what may be the reason that this code doesn't work. I would be very grateful for any help :)

Comment: Looks like you might be missing the closing `"` on the `src` attribute. Sharing the markup generated by the PHP could help too.

Answer (score -1):

You should check that the $produkt['img'] here

```
<img src="telewizory/' . $produkt['img'] . ' class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Sheep">'
            . ' </td>
```

is replaced with the expected value from the DB.

Comment: I checked and  $produkt['img'] is giving the right value so the problem is still unsolved